# How to get all the stores available within a bounding box in PHP?

Tags: mysql, dictionary, bounding-box

I have a table containing 'places', each place with a name and lat, lng coordinates. Given a bounding box of coordinates (lat/lng perimeters), what is an efficient way to retrieve only the places within that box? . I have the coordinates of all the corners of the map now, I want to get all the stores within that rectangle.

[image]

I want this to be done in PHP and MySQL. I am trying to use a `BETWEEN` query, but unable to find the stores. My code is as follows:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * from myTable
    WHERE lon BETWEEN '$west_lon' AND '$east_lon'
    AND lat BETWEEN '$south_lat' AND '$north_lat'
";
```

Comment: Did you run that query on MySQL console? Were there any results?

Comment: Hi my problem Solved. The problem was i didn't added "("  in multiple Between query. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do the wariables `$south_lon` and `$north_lon` exist?  `$west_lon`and `$east_lon` would be more logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi At last i Solved My Problem. There was a silly mistake in Query.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `MyTable`  WHERE (longitude BETWEEN '$west_long' AND '$east_long') AND (lat BETWEEN '$north_lat' AND '$south_lat')";
```

if anyone finds a better way please Post here. I don't know whether its Correct or not.